# Google App Engine download_data authentication error

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have read the numerous questions on this, but found no solution that works :(

```
$ appcfg.py download_data --url=http://THING.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=backup1 .
08:47 PM Application: THING
08:47 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20120910.204726
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20120910.204726.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20120910.204726.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to THING.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Authentication Failed
```

So I have several questions about what's going on:

1. Why does this not ask me for my password, when in almost every other question I've seen it does? Is it because I've already uploaded a new version of my app and signed in?
2. Why do some people have to put application='s~THING' in their command line (does not help me).
3. I'm using a gmail address as my admin, so presumably that means its not related to any of the OpenID bugs given as answers to other similar questions?
4. I have `builtins: - remote_api: on` in my app.yaml (which is in this directory - hence the ".", right?), do I need to put a handler in?
5. The request for /_ah/remote_api goes to my main ("/.*") handler! Is that the cause of the problem?
6. How can I fix any of these things?

Edit:
Sebastian kindly pointed me in the right direction, but I now have this error:

```
$ appcfg.py download_data --application='s~THING' --url=http://THING.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=backup1 --kind=Article .
09:47 PM Application: s~THING (was: THING)
09:47 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20120910.214744
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20120910.214744.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20120910.214744.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to THING.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Downloading kinds: ['Article']
.[ERROR   ] [WorkerThread-1] WorkerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 176, in WorkOnItems
    status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
  File "/home/me/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 764, in PerformWork
    transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
  File "/home/me/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1170, in _TransferItem
    self, retry_parallel=self.first)
  File "/home/me/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1471, in GetEntities
    results = self._QueryForPbs(query)
  File "/home/me/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1442, in _QueryForPbs
    raise datastore._ToDatastoreError(e)
Error: API error 4 (datastore_v3: NEED_INDEX): no matching index found.
[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down...
[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-1: API error 4 (datastore_v3: NEED_INDEX): no matching index found.

[INFO    ] Have 10 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 10 entities (12985 bytes) transferred in 1.6 seconds
```

Comment: Did you deploy a version with the remote_api builtin enabled? Can you post your app.yaml file.

Comment: remote_api is on, but I don't think any of this is supported by the go GAE runtime

Comment: Did you follow the steps outlined here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadingdata#Setting_Up_remote_api

Comment: No, no I did not... I was looking at the python ones... Thank you. Ok, new error :)

Comment: Can you try without the final dot, and also without the kind option.

Comment: Same error, 28 entities. However the file does seem to be written to, and can be uploaded to my dev server. However more errors await there: API error 1 (datastore_v3: BAD_REQUEST): ApplicationError: 1 app "THING" cannot access app "s~THING"'s data

Answer (score 0):

I am still left with errors (see above) but the basics appear to be covered by https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadingdata
as recommended in a comment. Thanks for that.
If I fix the other errors I will update this.

Comment: Did you follow the steps outlined here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadingdata#Setting_Up_remote_api

Answer (score 0):

There's a small bug in the Go remote_api support. To work around it you can either add the relevant index, or use a dummy Python version to download the data. It should be fixed in a future release.